# C# Excel Interop InvalidCastException when trying to change Shape.Fill.Backcolor

Tags: c#, excel, exception, interop

I am getting an error when I try to change the background color of a new shape created via C# on an Excel worksheet.  I have added sample code below which produces the error.  The below code works fine on my old PC with Office 2013 installed but when run on a clients machine or my new PC (Windows 10 Office 2016) I get an InvalidCastException (exception pasted below) on the `Shape.getFill()` call and in a few other calls as well.

All the calls that throw seem to be related to getting formatting objects (e.g. it also occurs on the `Chart.PlotArea.Format.get_Line()` call.  Most of the other C# Excel Interop calls I make are working fine.  For example, I can create shapes and charts, write and read from cells but when I try to change the formatting of some objects this error occurs.  When I compile and run the below code on the new laptop I get an vague InvalidCastException when compiled and run on the old laptop it works without error.  Compiling and running on the old machine does not fix this issue on the new one.  I have tried installing the 2010 PIA on the new PC with no luck either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### Code example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestOfficeError {
    static class Program {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbooks wbs = app.Workbooks;
            Excel.Workbook wb = wbs.Add();
            Excel.Sheets sheets = wb.Sheets;
            Excel.Worksheet sheet = sheets[1];

            Excel.Shape shape = sheet.Shapes.AddShape(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 10, 10, 100, 100);

            //Exception thrown on this line. See exception below.
            shape.Fill.BackColor.RGB = 0;

            wb.Activate();

            SafeRelease(sheet);
            SafeRelease(sheets);
            SafeRelease(wb);
            SafeRelease(wbs);
            SafeRelease(app);
            FinalCleanup();

        }

        static void SafeRelease(object obj) {
            if (obj != null){
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(obj);
            }
        }

        static void FinalCleanup() {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Exception

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Return argument has an invalid type.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.ValidateReturnArg(Object arg, Type paramType)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PropagateOutParameters(IMessage msg, Object[] outArgs, Object returnValue)
       at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape.get_Fill()
       at TestOfficeError.Program.Main() in c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestOfficeError\TestOfficeError\Program.cs:line 28
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue by any chance in the past two years? I got the same error and I don't know how to fix it or come up with a workaround in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue with the Excel.Shape.Line property. The problem was that the user had the 64-bit version of Office 2010 installed. Changing it out for the 32-bit version solved the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are both already running 32 bit version of Office.

Comment: I have the same problem but I can't change the client's computer in any way. What would be the solution on the part of the developer?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem using the type `dynamic` instead of `Excel.Shape`.

This is only a workaround but it's working.